# c program hangs when gets used in structure

Tags: c

I am trying to learn structures and the below code is having some sort of error, not logical but just shows up while execution saying, the file has stopped working. Occurs right after gets(s2.name)

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct student
{
  char *name;
  float mark1,mark2,mark3;
  float total;
};
int main()
{
struct student s1,s2,s[3];
s1.mark1=6;s1.mark2=7;s1.mark3=8;
s1.total = s1.mark1+s1.mark2+s1.mark3;
printf("\nEnter the name of s2 : ");
gets(s2.name);
/*when above line is inserted program hangs and code below does not execute*/
puts(s2.name);
s1.name = "shanky";
puts(s1.name);
getch();
return 0;
}
```

No compilation error obviously. Using gcc compiler

Comment: Undefined behavior for using the value of an object with automatic storage duration while it is indeterminate.

Comment: Good idea for one statement per line. i.e. ; -> start a new line

Comment: [DO NOT use `gets()`, it is dangerous](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2173917). use [`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead.

Comment: `No compilation error obviously`...is that so?

Comment: @Sourav Yes there were no compilation error

Comment: Are you familiar with GDB? It is immensely useful to know how to step a program through a debugger (just an FYI).

Comment: @shanky What kind of compiler are you using, and did you enable warnings?

Comment: @EOF No. Warnings are disabled in gcc by default. I really missed something here

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to allocate memory for the name member of the struct.  It is a pointer, but unless you malloc() some memory, you have no idea where it points to.

Try something like s2.name = malloc(80).  Make sure you check the return value, and note that gets() is unsafe.  Don't use that in production code. (or rather, don't use gets() at all).

Comment: `but unless you malloc() some memory`..how about assigning a pointer to another statically allocated variable?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: that works for one structure variable; it rapidly becomes untenable when there's more than one variable of that type kicking around.